# Redirecionar uma url para dentro de uma pasta, sem mostrar nome

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho uma url local:

http://localhost/projeto/view/
e
http://localhost/projeto/view/cadastro.php

gostaria que atravez do htaccess removesse o /view/, exemplo:

http://localhost/projeto
ou
http://localhost/projeto/cadastro.php

Comment: Só tem essa URL na aplicação ou há outras? Se há, quais são?

Comment: Só há essa, mais no queria colocar as paginas direto na raiz

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona as linhas a seguir no seu .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !projeto/view/
RewriteRule (.*) /../$1 [L]
```

Comment: não deu muito certo, retornou o erro: Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.